# How to make elements fixed in bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

[image: Gallary]

[image: Image at small screen]

Hello!
I am making gallary responsive for all screen in bootstrap. I wrote some media queries also for that.
At small screen like at 100px-200px the add-to-cart icon is displaying below the "Details".

I tried to fix this by writing position:fixed for icon but it is now only displaying at the bottom of last image.
Please help me in solving this issue.

Css Code

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 100px) and (max-width : 377px) {

 .basket-logo
 {position:fixed;
 bottom:0;}


    .col-xs-6 
    {
        margin-right:2px;
    }

}
```

php Code

```
        echo "
            <div id='single_product' class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>

        <h3 style='color:white'; align='center'>$pro_title</h3> 

        <img src='admin_area/product_images/u_seller_product_img/$pro_img'  width='180' height='180' /> <br>

        <p style='color:white'><b>Price: $  $pro_price </b></p>

        <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' class='detail_hover'>Details</a>

        <a href='Home.php?add_cart=$pro_id' style='color:white;' class='basket-logo'>
        <span  class='fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x'></span></a> 


            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS part, you can try `display:inline-block` for the `basket-class` :

```
.basket-logo {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT**

The `position:fixed` means that all `basket-logo` class content stay at the same fixed position (at 0px from the bottom in your case). You can remove that rule and the `bottom:0;` too.

Comment: No dear, i want to display the icon in front of Details. Also see in image that, why the price breaks ?

Comment: See my updated question in which i have shared my gallary

Comment: Like gallary, i want to display the icon in front of Details

Comment: Ok, but it's hard to test solutions with the picture. When on the page, you can Inspect Element and try some CSS rules in "live". BTW, try to add `display:inline-block;` in the css of `basket-logo` class.

Comment: Anyhow, i will try by inspecting this

Comment: Ok, good luck, I'll delete this answer since it's not a solution and will not help others.

Answer (score 0):

make the structure like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" > 
<div class="col-xs-12"> - title </div>
<div class="col-xs-12"> - image</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">- price</div>

<div class="col-xs-6"> -detail </div>  
<div class="col-xs-6"> -cart </div>
</div>
```